# Redirect example.com/filename.jpg to example.com/uploads/filename.jpg with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect `example.com/filename.jpg` to `example.com/uploads/filename.jpg` with `.htaccess`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

.htaccess in your web root directory:

```
RewriteRule ^filename.jpg$   uploads/filename.jpg [L]
```

Or, you can write a more general rule that will match all requests for /*.jpg with  /uploads/*.jpg

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)+.jpg$   uploads/$1.jpg [L]
```

As with all things, you're better off actually learning how to use mod_rewrite instead of just asking for the answer to very specific examples:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html